# Помощь с использованием библиотеки jQuery

Tags: javascript

задание - После имени человека Добавить  и / или  если у нее в соответствии сыновья и / или дочери.
Проблема в том, что в колонках  где нету не сыновей, не дочерей всё равно ставятся "смайлы". Как это исправить?

```js
 $(document.body).ready(function () {
       $('tr td:first-child').each(function(i,elem) {
    if ($(this).next().text()=='Жін.') {
      $(this).css("color", "#ac007c");
    }
    if ($(this).next().text()=='Чол.') {
       $(this).css("color", "#045acf");
 }
  });
$('table tr td:last-child').each(function(){
  $(this).text( $(this).text() + ' $' );//или какой-то другой символ

  let val = parseFloat( $(this).text() );
  if( val < 4000 && val > 999 ){
    $(this).html( '<i>' + $(this).html() + '</i>' );
  } else if( val >= 4000 && val < 6000 ) {
    $(this).html( '<u>' + $(this).html() + '</u>' );
  } else if( val >= 6000 ) {
    $(this).html( '<b>' + $(this).html() + '</b>' );
  }
});
 
$('table tr td:first-child')
            .filter(function(index, text){
                let row1 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(4)").text();
                let row2 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(5)").text();
                return row2==1 || row1==0 || row2  && row1  ;
            })
        .append("");

 $('table tr td:first-child')
            .filter(function(index, text){
                let row1 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(4)").text();
                let row2 = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(5)").text();
                return row2==0 || row1==1 || row2  && row1  ;
            })
        .append("");
});
```

```css
 body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 50px;
        }
        table {
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        td{
            min-width: 50px;
            padding: 2px 10px;
        }
        td:first-child{
            text-align: left;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <table id="mytable" border=1><tr><th>Ім'я</th><th>Стать</th><th>Вік</th><th>Одружений(a)</th><th>Сини</th><th>Доньки</th><th>Дом. тварина</th><th>Зарплата</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Додковська Яна</td><td>Жін.</td><td>42</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>метелик</td><td>334</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Яцуненкова Юлія</td><td>Жін.</td><td>31</td><td>Ні</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>пацюк</td><td>788</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Білай Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>51</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>жаба</td><td>3821</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ярюшенк Дмитро</td><td>Чол.</td><td>62</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>кіт</td><td>822</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Сольвейстров Марк</td><td>Чол.</td><td>61</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>скорпіон</td><td>348</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Вєльковський Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>66</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>метелик</td><td>722</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Каретан Андрій</td><td>Чол.</td><td>44</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>метелик</td><td>200</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Гіроєва Дарина</td><td>Жін.</td><td>62</td><td>Так</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>-</td><td>5743</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Тяфф Іван</td><td>Чол.</td><td>46</td><td>Так</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>миша</td><td>7843</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Гем Денис</td><td>Чол.</td><td>37</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>3</td><td>ящірка</td><td>1881</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ткачюк Станіслав</td><td>Чол.</td><td>21</td><td>Ні</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>миша</td><td>270</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Мазєренко Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>20</td><td>Так</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>равлик</td><td>8307</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Піліщук Антон</td><td>Чол.</td><td>36</td><td>Ні</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>креветка</td><td>291</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Накядень Яна</td><td>Жін.</td><td>42</td><td>Так</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>скорпіон</td><td>2604</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Білий Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>52</td><td>Ні</td><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>-</td><td>456</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Дінел Сергій</td><td>Чол.</td><td>44</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>жаба</td><td>201</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Павлінчак Микита</td><td>Чол.</td><td>37</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>кіт</td><td>773</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Хєдак Валентина</td><td>Жін.</td><td>31</td><td>Ні</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>кролик</td><td>517</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ігнатянко Ярослав</td><td>Чол.</td><td>36</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>лисиця</td><td>282</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Шурбюна Любов</td><td>Жін.</td><td>25</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>пацюк</td><td>5647</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Тиг Юрій</td><td>Чол.</td><td>40</td><td>Ні</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>-</td><td>5295</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Лешкя Денис</td><td>Чол.</td><td>69</td><td>Ні</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>змія</td><td>200</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Кул Владислав</td><td>Чол.</td><td>61</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>равлик</td><td>3402</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Короткай Віталій</td><td>Чол.</td><td>55</td><td>Так</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>креветка</td><td>200</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Гепчук Сергій</td><td>Чол.</td><td>26</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>равлик</td><td>1736</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Рудай Богдан</td><td>Чол.</td><td>37</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>ящірка</td><td>3908</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Крапева Олена</td><td>Жін.</td><td>50</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>креветка</td><td>6734</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Бугієвич Тетяна</td><td>Жін.</td><td>40</td><td>Ні</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>равлик</td><td>200</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ратішна Валерія</td><td>Жін.</td><td>44</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>миша</td><td>340</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Брут Максим</td><td>Чол.</td><td>50</td><td>Так</td><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>кіт</td><td>392</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Кезач Світлана</td><td>Жін.</td><td>24</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>жаба</td><td>213</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Спісив Сергій</td><td>Чол.</td><td>35</td><td>Так</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>жаба</td><td>3364</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Бригарчек Олена</td><td>Жін.</td><td>54</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>равлик</td><td>6399</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ліщенка Анна</td><td>Жін.</td><td>65</td><td>Ні</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>скорпіон</td><td>2041</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Звер Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>27</td><td>Так</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>курка</td><td>246</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Семенівна Софія</td><td>Жін.</td><td>31</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>кролик</td><td>5598</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Казарян Олексій</td><td>Чол.</td><td>50</td><td>Так</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>жаба</td><td>2071</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Зацєва Антоніна</td><td>Жін.</td><td>36</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>миша</td><td>3061</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Невік Артем</td><td>Чол.</td><td>60</td><td>Ні</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>кролик</td><td>5682</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Саулкі Денис</td><td>Чол.</td><td>53</td><td>Ні</td><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>-</td><td>327</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Кудінав Сергій</td><td>Чол.</td><td>24</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>ящірка</td><td>4493</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Тіфт Яна</td><td>Жін.</td><td>61</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>кролик</td><td>4435</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Оріщенко Алла</td><td>Жін.</td><td>64</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>-</td><td>4974</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Пювань Павло</td><td>Чол.</td><td>70</td><td>Так</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>жаба</td><td>2399</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Зягоскін Богдан</td><td>Чол.</td><td>46</td><td>Ні</td><td>0</td><td>3</td><td>метелик</td><td>200</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Биндар Вікторія</td><td>Жін.</td><td>31</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>собака</td><td>3578</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Соліванова Ганна</td><td>Жін.</td><td>32</td><td>Так</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>равлик</td><td>896</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Нікіток Діана</td><td>Жін.</td><td>32</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>пацюк</td><td>4026</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Біланенкий Віктор</td><td>Чол.</td><td>42</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>3</td><td>кролик</td><td>1031</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Стельмух Євген</td><td>Чол.</td><td>56</td><td>Так</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>змія</td><td>585</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вероятно изначально планировали сделать добавлением этих символов в одной функции а потом разделили на две, но не упростили код?
Смотрите, вы в первой функции добавляете картинку для сыновей. Вам нужно проверить, есть ли в столбце 4 число отличной от нуля. Тогда зачем вообще вы там берете 5ю колонку? Аналогично для дочерей, зачем вы там тащите четвертую? В каждой функции надо проверить свою колонку и все.

```js
$('table tr td:first-child')
            .filter(function(index, text){
                let sc = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(4)").text();
                return sc > 0;
            })
        .append("");

 $('table tr td:first-child')
            .filter(function(index, text){
                let dc = +$(this).parent().children(":eq(5)").text();
                return dc > 0  ;
            })
        .append("");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <table id="mytable" border=1><tr><th>Ім'я</th><th>Стать</th><th>Вік</th><th>Одружений(a)</th><th>Сини</th><th>Доньки</th><th>Дом. тварина</th><th>Зарплата</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Додковська Яна</td><td>Жін.</td><td>42</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>метелик</td><td>334</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Яцуненкова Юлія</td><td>Жін.</td><td>31</td><td>Ні</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>пацюк</td><td>788</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Білай Олександр</td><td>Чол.</td><td>51</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>жаба</td><td>3821</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ярюшенк Дмитро</td><td>Чол.</td><td>62</td><td>Так</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>кіт</td><td>822</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Сольвейстров Марк</td><td>Чол.</td><td>61</td><td>Так</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>скорпіон</td><td>348</td></tr>
        
    </table>
```

Но я бы еще на вашем месте несколько поменял логику работы. Вы почему то берете первую ячейку каждой строки, потом тащите родителя, потом снова ищите дочерние ячейки. Перебирайте просто строки. И с ними работайте.
Доступ к ячейка по номеру тоже плохая затея, если структура таблицу вдруг изменится, то код придется менять. В данной случае ячейки лучше обозначит классами. 
Да и добавление иконок проще сделать средствами css.

```js
$("tbody tr").each(function(){
   let sc = +$(this).find(".sons").text(); //children().eq(1)
   let dc = +$(this).find(".daughters").text();
   console.log(sc,dc);
   $(this).toggleClass("has-sons", sc > 0)
          .toggleClass("has-daughters", dc > 0);
});
```

```css
tr.has-sons td:first-child::after{
   content: "";
}

tr.has-daughters td:first-child::after {
  content: "";
}

tr.has-sons+tr.has-daughters td:first-child::after {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mytable" border=1>
  <thead>  
    <tr><th>Ім'я</th><th>Сини</th><th>Доньки</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
    <tr><td>Додковська Яна</td><td class="sons">0</td><td class="daughters">1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Яцуненкова Юлія</td><td class="sons">1</td><td class="daughters">0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Білай Олександр</td><td class="sons">1</td><td class="daughters">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ярюшенк Дмитро</td><td class="sons">1</td><td class="daughters">1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Сольвейстров Марк</td><td class="sons">0</td><td class="daughters">0</td></tr>
  </tbody>        
</table>
```